# JavaScript google-spreadsheet API logging not working properly

Tags: javascript, async-await, google-sheets-api

I am a beginner at Javascript.
Trying to read data from GoogleSheets using google-spreadsheet API(https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)

For some reason, console.log is not working in below code.
Also, I am getting all the google sheet info printed in the console, which is so much that I am not able to see the full log.

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require("google-spreadsheet");
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet("****************-*******-*******");
const serviceAccountCreds = require("./serviceAccountCredentials.json");
let expenseSheet;

// Load envs in process
process.env["GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL"] = serviceAccountCreds.client_email;
process.env["GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY"] = serviceAccountCreds.private_key;

// authenticate to the google sheet
const authenticate = async () => {
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
        client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    });
};
authenticate();

//load Spreadsheet doc info
const docInfo = async () => {
    await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
    console.log(doc.title); // This line does not seem to work
};
docInfo();
```

I am requiring help with 2 things.

1. The console.log does not seem to print anything.
2. The Google sheet information is getting printed, which I don't want it to be.

Thanks in advance.

To check the console.log, I tried to output console log to a file, by using the below command in windows.
`nodejs readSheet.js > path_to_file`
Even though the file is generated, there is no log in that file.

Comment: When I tested your script, the spreadsheet title from `console.log(doc.title)` is shown in the console. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `The console.log does not seem to print anything.` and `The Google sheet information is getting printed`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue?